# Init.d script not updating git repository

Tags: git, bash, shell, ubuntu, init

I have the following init.d script running on my ubuntu machine:

```
# /etc/init.d/do-updates
cd /home/ubuntu/Fox;git pull
sudo /home/ubuntu/Fo/batch_update_process.py 1>> /home/ubuntu/updates_log.txt
```

It is correctly runs and write to `updates_log.txt`, however it is not updating the git repository. Any ideas why this is occurring or what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: What, if any, errors are returned by `git pull`? Since you are only writing `stdout` to `updates_log.txt`, your error messages should be written to the screen. Assuming `/home/ubuntu/Fox` is the local copy of the repository, then either there is nothing to update, or there are commits that need to take place before `git pull`

Comment: Does the script work if run by hand? If so, I'd check which user is used by init.d to execute the script and that no issues with the file system privileges are generated. HTH

Answer (score 1):

Is the difference between the cd /home/ubuntu/Fox and the sudo /home/ubuntu/Fo/... intended or is it a typo?

Put all the commands in a subshell and redirect all the output to the log file and you will most likely find what's wrong in the log file.

```
( cd /home/ubuntu/Fox;git pull ; sudo /home/ubuntu/Fo/batch_update_process.py ) >> /home/ubuntu/updates_log.txt
```